# An error occurs in the overridden function of XCUITest

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, xcode11.3, xcode11.4

An error occurs in the overridden function of XCUITest.
I have never mentioned XCUITest.

The error is: "Method does not override method in superclass".

This happens when you change Xcode from version 11.4 beta 2 to 11.3.1 and build.
what should I do?

```
import XCTest

class SampleAppUITests: XCTestCase {

    override func setUpWithError() throws {
        // Put setup code here. This method is called before the invocation of each test method in the class.

        // In UI tests it is usually best to stop immediately when a failure occurs.
        continueAfterFailure = false

        // In UI tests it’s important to set the initial state - such as interface orientation - required for your tests before they run. The setUp method is a good place to do this.
    }

    override func tearDownWithError() throws {
        // Put teardown code here. This method is called after the invocation of each test method in the class.
    }

    func testExample() throws {
        // UI tests must launch the application that they test.
        let app = XCUIApplication()
        app.launch()

        // Use recording to get started writing UI tests.
        // Use XCTAssert and related functions to verify your tests produce the correct results.
    }

    func testLaunchPerformance() throws {
        if #available(macOS 10.15, iOS 13.0, tvOS 13.0, *) {
            // This measures how long it takes to launch your application.
            measure(metrics: [XCTOSSignpostMetric.applicationLaunch]) {
                XCUIApplication().launch()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Explained in the release notes:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode_release_notes/xcode_11_4_beta_3_release_notes

You (the template) are calling methods that don’t exist when you use Xcode 11.3.1 or before. Use availability to replace `setUpWithError` and `tearDownWithError` (Swift 5.2) with simple `setUp` and `tearDown` (Swift 5.1).